# Changing CPU info on chip itself?

Tags: cpu

I would like to know, how computers know, what CPU is installed at the moment. My hypothesis is that some info about CPU is stored in someplace in CPU. And if so, there may be method to overwrite that info. Is it possible to change that info?

Comment: To what end? ..

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the CPU information is stored within the CPU itself.

No, it is not able to be edited or changed.

The CPU identity information will be set in stone at the time the CPU itself is manufactured, effectively burned into the chip as physical logic gates identifying the chip.

Not being able to change this is a good thing, for many reasons.

First, it prevents people attempting to sell lower price parts with the identities of higher priced parts and wasting other peoples time.

Secondly it prevents people or software from effectively rendering a system dead by applying microcode updates for the wrong processor. If a chip were to report the wrong ID then it may be that BIOS updates, Windows security microcode updates, or Linux microcode loaders would load data for the wrong chip. This could (at best) make the chip unstable, or at worst completely non-functional. The only fix would be to take the chip out, rewrite the correct ID to the chip in a system without updates, and the put it back in the original PC.